# Prevent clicking on link while page loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a web page with some links, and I need to intercept the link-clicking event by jQuery. The task is finished well, but then a problem arises: if the user click a link when JavaScript doesn't finish loading, it link to another page (which is an error).

I have tried to find a way to disable link-clicking before page loading finish, but the best solution now is that I must add `onclick="return false;"` into my links, which is not very elegant. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Why not send the href as another attribute, and then copy that attribute to href when the link is ready to be clicked on?

Comment: @jrockway: thanks for the recommendation, but I think it's not convenient to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I have worked out: Using a masker put in front of the link to prevent clicking event.

```
<div class="LinkMasker"></div>

.LinkMasker {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: ...px;
    height: ...px;
}
```

After page loading & my event are all registered, I remove the masker:

```
$('.LinkMasker').remove();
```

Comment: I know it's a minority, but users with Javascript turned off are unable to use your site this way.

Comment: @kapa: it's sad, but none of the methods here will work without javascript.

Comment: But those scripts will simply not run, and the links remain clickable. In turn, you disable everything, and nothing is usable.

Comment: What you say is true. And that's what our customer means in this case. Sometimes we don't need perfection for an in-house workflow project, which is used only by a handful of people. If the target is broader audience, your concern would be relevant

Comment: That is fine, but then you need a disclaimer (which I added with my comment). Your question/answer is not only for you, and not even primarily for you, but for future visitors.

Answer (score 6):

You could try using an initialization script:

```
<script language="javascript">

var loaded = false;

function SetLoaded() { loaded = true; }

window.onload = SetLoaded;

</script>
```

Then you can add `onclick="return loaded;"` to your href. Since loaded won't be true until the page loads, it should disable any link with this added.

Answer (score 3):

Today i was facing this issue so i did R&D and figured out another way of it.
document.readyState will be 'complete' after page load so you can check its value like.

```
 if(document.readyState=='complete')
 {
   //// call script or do anything which you want to do.
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually what I want is prevent the clicking until finishing page-loading. Anyway, thank you for your attitude. Not many one answers old question

Answer (score 1):

Have jQuery set up the hrefs in the links in your document.ready(). Maybe prefix your links with a '#', and have jQuery strip them out.